# Como implantar formulário como aplicativo web ? [Google Script]

Tags: aplicação-web, google, google-sheets

Bom dia Senhores estou com dúvida enorme como publicar este formulário como aplicativo web ,ele esta como referência a planilha ativa e na web vai precisar referenciar a planilha vi url não sei como fazer isto.

```js
script type = "text/javascript">


document.getElementById("btnpesquisar").addEventListener("click", Pesquisar);
 
  function Pesquisar(){
  
  
  var criteriopesquisa = document.getElementById("Campo1").value;
  
  if (criteriopesquisa.trim().length == 0){  
   alert("Precisa fornecer critério para pesquisa!");
   return false;
  };
  
 
  
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(Carregar).PesquisarDados(criteriopesquisa);
  
  function Carregar(retorno){  
   
  if (retorno != "Não encontrado!"){
  
  document.getElementById("Campo1").value = retorno[0]
  M.updateTextFields();
  document.getElementById("Campo2").value = retorno[1]
  M.updateTextFields();
  document.getElementById("Campo3").value = retorno[2]
  M.updateTextFields();
  document.getElementById("Campo4").value = retorno[3]
  M.updateTextFields();
  document.getElementById("Campo5").value = retorno[4]
  M.updateTextFields();
  document.getElementById("Campo6").value = retorno[5]
  M.updateTextFields();
  
  }else{
  
  alert("Não encontrado!");
   Limpar();
   
  }
    
  }
  }
  
  document.getElementById("btnlimpar").addEventListener("click", Limpar);
 
  function Limpar(){
  
  document.getElementById("Campo1").value = "";
  document.getElementById("Campo2").value = "";
  document.getElementById("Campo3").value = "";
  document.getElementById("Campo4").value = "";
  document.getElementById("Campo5").value = "";
  document.getElementById("Campo6").value = "";
    
  }
  
  
  document.getElementById("btnexcluir").addEventListener("click", Excluir);
 
  function Excluir(){
  
  
  var criteriopesquisa = document.getElementById("Campo1").value;
  
  if (criteriopesquisa.trim().length == 0){  
   alert("Precisa fornecer critério para pesquisa!");
   return false;
  };
   
  var r = confirm("Deseja Realmente Excluir este item?");

if (r==false){
alert("Operação Cancelada")
return false;
}

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(Carregar).ExcluirDados(criteriopesquisa);
  
  function Carregar(retorno){  
   
  if (retorno != "Não encontrado!"){
  
  Limpar();
  
  alert("Excluído com sucesso!");
  
  }else{
  
  alert(retorno);
  }
    
  }
  }
  
  document.getElementById("btnsalvar").addEventListener("click", Salvar);
   
   function Salvar(){
   
   var Campo1 = document.getElementById("Campo1").value;
   var Campo2 = document.getElementById("Campo2").value;
   var Campo3 = document.getElementById("Campo3").value;
   var Campo4 = document.getElementById("Campo4").value;
   var Campo5 = document.getElementById("Campo5").value;
   var Campo6 = document.getElementById("Campo6").value;
   
   
   if (Campo1.trim().length != 0){   
   alert("Campo1 precisa ser vazio porque é gerado automaticamente ao salvar!");
   return false;   
   }
   
   if (Campo2.trim().length == 0 || Campo3.trim().length == 0 || Campo4.trim().length == 0 || 
   Campo5.trim().length == 0 || Campo6.trim().length == 0){
   
   alert("Preencher todos os campos, exceto o campo1");
       
   }else{
   
  var Dados ={
 

 Campo2: Campo2,
 Campo3: Campo3,
 Campo4: Campo4,
 Campo5: Campo5,
 Campo6: Campo6,
  
   
   };
   
   
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(Salvar).SalvarDados(Dados);
   
  function Salvar(retorno) {
  
  alert(retorno);

  Limpar();
  
     }
}
}
 


document.getElementById("btneditar").addEventListener("click", Editar);
   
   function Editar(){
   
   var Campo1 = document.getElementById("Campo1").value;
   var Campo2 = document.getElementById("Campo2").value;
   var Campo3 = document.getElementById("Campo3").value;
   var Campo4 = document.getElementById("Campo4").value;
   var Campo5 = document.getElementById("Campo5").value;
   var Campo6 = document.getElementById("Campo6").value;
      
   
   if (Campo1.trim().length == 0 || Campo2.trim().length == 0 || Campo3.trim().length == 0 || Campo4.trim().length == 0 || 
   Campo5.trim().length == 0 || Campo6.trim().length == 0){
   
   alert("Preencher todos os campos");
       
   }else{
   
  var Dados ={
 
 Campo1: Campo1,
 Campo2: Campo2,
 Campo3: Campo3,
 Campo4: Campo4,
 Campo5: Campo5,
 Campo6: Campo6,
  
   
   };
   
   
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(Editar).EditarDados(Dados);
   
  function Editar(retorno) {
  
  alert(retorno);
  if(retorno != "ID não encontrado!" ){
  Limpar();
  }
     }
}
}
  
  
  
</script>
```

```css
function ExibirFormulario(){
   
var Form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Formulario");
  
var MostrarForm = Form.evaluate();
  
MostrarForm.setTitle("FORMULÁRIO").setHeight(265).setWidth(650);
  
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(MostrarForm, "FORMULÁRIO");

  
}


function Chamar(Arquivo){

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(Arquivo).getContent();
```

```html
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TI7A4p_7T6QY-JYzU-9bjFWQV10afaqGLyQkjqCw7xw/edit#gid=547063359"

function PesquisarDados(criteriopesquisa){

var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var guiadados = planilha.getSheetByName("Dados");

var dados = guiadados.getRange(2, 1, guiadados.getLastRow(),6).getValues();

for(var linha = 0; linha<dados.length; linha++){
          
     if(dados[linha][0] == criteriopesquisa || dados[linha][1] == criteriopesquisa){           
       
        var Carregar={};
        
        var data = Utilities.formatDate(dados[linha][4], Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
        var valor = dados[linha][5].toLocaleString("pt-BR");
        
        Carregar.Campo1 = dados[linha][0]
        Carregar.Campo2 = dados[linha][1];
        Carregar.Campo3 = dados[linha][2];      
        Carregar.Campo4 = dados[linha][3];         
        Carregar.Campo5 = data;
        Carregar.Campo6 = valor;
    
         return ([Carregar.Campo1,Carregar.Campo2, Carregar.Campo3, Carregar.Campo4, Carregar.Campo5, Carregar.Campo6])     
         
         
     }
     


}

return "Não encontrado!";


}


function ExcluirDados(criteriopesquisa){

var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var guiadados = planilha.getSheetByName("Dados");

var dados = guiadados.getRange(2, 1, guiadados.getLastRow()).getValues();

for(var linha = 0; linha<dados.length; linha++){
          
     if(dados[linha][0] == criteriopesquisa){           
       
           var linha = linha + 2;
           
           guiadados.deleteRow(linha);           
    
         return "Excluído!"    
         
         
     }

}

return "Não encontrado!";


}


function SalvarDados(Dados){

var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var guiadados = planilha.getSheetByName("Dados");

var novoid = Math.max.apply(null, guiadados.getRange("A2:A").getValues()); 
var novoid = novoid + 1


var linha = guiadados.getLastRow() + 1;

guiadados.getRange(linha, 1).setValue(novoid);
guiadados.getRange(linha, 2).setValue([Dados.Campo2]);
guiadados.getRange(linha, 3).setValue([Dados.Campo3]);
guiadados.getRange(linha, 4).setValue([Dados.Campo4]);
guiadados.getRange(linha, 5).setValue([Dados.Campo5]);
guiadados.getRange(linha, 6).setValue([Dados.Campo6]);

guiadados.getRange(linha, 5).setNumberFormat('dd"/"mm"/"yyyy');

return "Salvo com sucesso!";



}



function EditarDados(Dados){

var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var guiadados = planilha.getSheetByName("Dados");

var criteriopesquisa = Dados.Campo1

var dados = guiadados.getRange(2, 1, guiadados.getLastRow()).getValues();

for(var linha = 0; linha<dados.length; linha++){
          
     if(dados[linha][0] == criteriopesquisa){   
     
      var linha = linha + 2;

      guiadados.getRange(linha, 2).setValue([Dados.Campo2]);
      guiadados.getRange(linha, 3).setValue([Dados.Campo3]);
      guiadados.getRange(linha, 4).setValue([Dados.Campo4]);
      guiadados.getRange(linha, 5).setValue([Dados.Campo5]);
      guiadados.getRange(linha, 6).setValue([Dados.Campo6]);

       guiadados.getRange(linha, 5).setNumberFormat('dd"/"mm"/"yyyy');

          return "Editado com sucesso!";
    }
}

return "ID não encontrado!";

}
```

[image: Base de dados]  [image: ao clicar no botão aparece formulário, no botão foi atribuído um script]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]